# How to use class validator decorator optionally in Nest.js dto

Tags: nestjs, dto, class-validator

I am using class validator in nest js validate the request data. In the request body I have a field called `isEmailOrPhone`. To validate email I need `IsEmail` decorator and to validate phone number I need `IsPhoneNumber` decorator in to validate them separetly.

But how can I validate a field where it can be both email or phone number? Is there any OR operation in class validator that gives true if any one of them is true?

Like:  `@IsEmaail() || @IsPhoneNumber()`

Update:

I also created custom validator like following.

```
import { registerDecorator, ValidationOptions, ValidationArguments, IsEmail, IsPhoneNumber } from 'class-validator';

export function IsEmailOrPhone(validationOptions?: ValidationOptions) {
  return function (object: Object, propertyName: string) {
    registerDecorator({
      name: 'IsEmailOrPhone',
      target: object.constructor,
      propertyName: propertyName,
      options: validationOptions,
      validator: {
        validate(value: any, args: ValidationArguments) {
          const isEmailValid = IsEmail(value);
          const isPhoneValid = IsPhoneNumber(value);
      
          return isEmailValid || isPhoneValid;
          
        },
      },
    });
  };
}
```

The decorator IsEmail and IsPhoneNumber are returning data of type `PropertyDecorator` but the validate function needs to return either `boolean` or `Promise<boolean>`.

So how can I send boolean data?

Comment: I think you should custom your validation, https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#custom-validation-decorators

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I used the custom validator from the link. But facing an issue. Please see the updated part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall correctly, you'll actually want to use `isEmail` and `isPhone` instead of `IsEmail` and `IsPhone`. From what I remember, the lowercase methods (`is*`) are the actual validation methods while the uppercase ones (`Is*`) are the decorators.